# How to make friendly custom URL for deployed app

Tags: google-app-maker

After deploying an App Maker app, how does one set a friendly URL, or custom domain, or make it appear in the list of your G Suite domain apps?

I've looked through App Settings and Edit Deployment, but there is nothing to be found, the unique deployment URL's a fairly difficult to remember.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible to my knowledge. Workarounds:
- add icon to the G Suite start button (via internal marketplace app)
- create a start workspace in Google Sites for all of your apps (or use Google orbitera)
- push a bookmark to your apps via Chrome management (login to chrome required by your user)

Comment: I did something similar to the a start workspace, I just created a "new" Sites page and embedded the URL into it.
Where is the "via internal marketplace app" you mention above? That sounds useful.

Comment: still no way to obtain a friendly url for the Google App Maker app?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up embedding it in a G Suite "new" sites page with the "embed URL" tool.
This isn't ideal, as it has a large header that takes up some room at the top, and the AppMaker web app already has a header. 
But it does provide a quick friendly URL.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround.

I purchased a .app domain though domains.google.com.

Then set a redirect from here to your published app maker app url through the portal.

As long as the user is using chrome and one of their chrome logged in profiles is their g-suite business account then the app seems to launch without any issues.

Its not perfect but that’s my current plan.